# Html Agility Pack Loop Through Tables - Adding node above as td inside tables until next tag

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, html-agility-pack

I am trying to loop through tables but the location information is used as grouped. How can I use the location info on each table until it changes on next? Kinda stuck here. Maybe adding h4 text as td on each table may solve the problem but I couldn't manage to do this. I am using selenium web driver.

So every h4 inner text will be used as location info under tables.

Sample Code:

```
<div>
<h4>location1</h4>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>16 May 2017</td>
            <td>fdfds</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h4>location2</h4>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>21 May 2017</td>
            <td>ghghhgh</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>25 May 2017</td>
            <td>hgfhfghfgh</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h4>location3</h4>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>29 May 2017</td>
            <td>ghhfhgfhfg</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>03 Jun 2017</td>
            <td>hjhjhj</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h4>location4</h4>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth3">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
        <col class="colwidth4">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2 Jul 2017</td>
            <td>jujujuj</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Please add some examples and post the code you have tried and explain why it didn't accomplish what you wanted including any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with js solution

```
 function test() {
                var loc = "";
                $('div').children().each(function () {
                    var type = $(this).prop('tagName');
                    if (type == "H4")
                    {
                        loc = $(this).text();
                    }
                    else if (type=="TABLE")
                    {
                        $(this).find('td').eq(0).before('<td>' + loc + '</td>');
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can wrap your h4+table into a div you can than pack everything into list via:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('your_selector');
```

And iterate through:

```
for (var i = 0; element = elements[i]; i++) {
h4header = element.getElementsByTagName('h4');
location = h4header.value;
table = element.getElementsByTagName('table');
// than you can do your rows via for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
};
```

But this solution kinda sloooow

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the answer. the problem with wrapping is there can be multiple tables under h4 that i need to match. each table needs to be another cell and with wrapping if there are 2 tables under h4 tag those will be single cell.

Comment: So you still can select multiple tables via:
var tables = element.querySelectorAll('your_table_selector');

And then progress on them one by one

Comment: Is there a way that I can add h4 as td into tables? Something like  $('h4').each(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil('h4').addBack()

Comment: Posibly you can use .prepend method... But im not shure if it would do what you want